# site_perl directory is missing in perl search path

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm noob in perl.

I used perl module installed on `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl` on CentOS 5. On CentOS 6 the directory is missing from perl search path (@INC).

On CentOS 5 perl -V output:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 8 subversion 8) configuration:
  .......
  .......
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Sep  3 2009 10:26:51
  @INC:
    /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
    /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
    .
```

On CentOS 6 perl -V output:

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 10 subversion 1) configuration:
  .....
  .....
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Jun 22 2012 13:27:28
  @INC:
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    .
```

Where should I put arch independent stuff now?

Comment: Is this a CPAN module, or a module you have written yourself?

Comment: @Borodin it's mine module

Comment: Then, as I said in my answer, either put it in your current working directory or - better - in a folder you have set aside for the purpose and set `PERL5LIB` to that path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain perl modules specific to your site should go in the directory given by:

```
perl -V:installsitelib
```

Consider creating a Makefile.PL or Build.PL and using that to install your module; doing

```
module-starter --module Your::Module::Name --author 'Your Name' --email your.email@example.com
```

will use [module-starter](http://p3rl.org/module-starter) to create a template distribution you can copy your code into.

Comment: Yes, except that there may not be one, and it looks like there isn't in this case.

Comment: @Borodin: really?  I would guess it is /usr/local/share/perl5 (and /usr/local/lib64/perl5 is likely installsitearch)

Comment: @ysthThis exactly what I was looking for. I needed to install pm while building rpm  -apparently there's predefined variable %{perl_sitelib}, which uses "perl -V:installsitelib" (see https://github.com/akozumpl/rpm/blob/master/macros.in)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a CPAN module then you should let the `cpan` utility decide where to put the files when the package is installed.

If you have written the module yourself then you can put the code in the current working directory (you will see that `.` is the last item in `@INC`) or in a separate directory specified by the environment variable `PERL5LIB` or in the Perl source file with `use lib`.

It is a bad idea to put development modules in a directory that is in every user's `@INC` list.

If you need a separate permanent directory for site libraries then you should rebuild Perl with an additional library path.